# WebAudioApi audio node stop not working in IOS UIWebView

Tags: uiwebview, web-audio-api

I am playing a list of audios in an html into UIWebView of IOS with the AudioContext object of the Javascript

eg :

```
var ctx = new AudioContext();
var node= ctx.createBufferSource();
node.buffer = AudioBufferFromAjaxCall;
node.connect(gainNodeObjCreatedEarlier);
node.start();
```

and the problem is node.stop(); isnt working , the audio started continuesly playing and not stopping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be helpful to know the version of safari that your UIWebView is using and whether or not you can reproduce it in the desktop version. Also, do you get any kind of log or error in the console?

In any case, have you tried passing a parameter to the stop method? something like

`node.stop(0);`

This argument specifies after how many seconds the node should stop. Sending 0 may help.

Comment: node.stop(0); was working fine it was my mistake that one condition blocked the node.stop(0); when i pause